# Alinear flex justify-right no funciona en chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox

> El contenido en firefox se alinea a la derecha pero en chrome y en edge no me estaría funcionando

```css
.grupocentrorigth{
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
    height: 700px;
    /* background-color: #48693b; */
}

.contenidosright{
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    /* background-color: antiquewhite; */
}

.rigthfacebook{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="grupocentrorigth" >
                    <div class="rigthfacebook contenidosright">
                        
                            <div class="fb-page"><a href="#">Link</a></blockquote></div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class=" contenidosright" >
                        <p>
                            Pellentesque placerat purus dui, vitae volutpat erat tincidunt non.
                            Pellentesque finibus sollicitudin arcu ac condimentum.
                            Phasellus sit amet lacus nec nisi viverra scelerisque. Quisque iaculis a purus fermentum iaculis.
                            Suspendisse urna leo, pulvinar accumsan dignissim at, auctor nec nulla.
                            In dignissim nulla quis mauris placerat pharetra. Etiam a quam vel mi convallis faucibus.
                            Sed convallis, ante sed consectetur sodales, tellus lacus semper sapien, at blandit turpis justo vel purus.
                        </p>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
```

[image: EDGE]

[image: CHROME]

[image: MOZILLA ES EL RESULTADO DESEADO]

[image: DETALLE DEL MAQUETADO]

Comment: El resultado que quiero obtener es el mostrado por mozilla. Agregué las fotos para que se pueda ver

Comment: Agrego otra foto con colores de fondo en las cajas para que vean la disposición. Muchas gracias

Comment: Informarte que `justify-content: right;` no existe en flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

comento lo siguiente:

- Noto que tratas de obtener un resultado de *3 columnas*, lo digo por que veo un espacio en blanco entre la columna de texto y la zona de las redes sociales
- Para este caso considero que si ya estás usando *flexbox* entonces no tiene caso estar aplicando el *float*
- Mas allá de eso considero que te sería mas conveniente aplicar una rejilla de 3 columnas para conseguir el resultado deseado

Entonces:

- Tendremos una sección principal con una distribución de tipo `grid`
- Estableceremos una división uniforme de 3 columnas
- Como originalmente solo tenemos contenido para 2, entonces podemos trabajar con las *grid areas* e indicar las áreas que nuestra rejilla va a tener

  - En este paso vinculamos el nombre que le damos al *grid-area* en el contenedor padre o *grid-container* con la clase que le damos a la etiqueta HTML que deseamos acomodar, que mas o menos se vería así:

### **Estructura**

```
grid-template-areas: "identificador";

.nombre-clase {
    grid-area: identificador;
}
```

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <style>
      :root {
        --borde-identificador: 1px solid crimson;
      }
      .section {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-template-areas: "descripcion vacio social";
        border: 1px solid;
        padding: 5px; /*para distinguir el borde del contenedor padre*/
      } 
      .descripcion {
        grid-area: descripcion;/*nombre del grid-area*/
        border: var(--borde-identificador);
      }
      .vacio {
        grid-area: vacio; /*nombre del grid-area*/
        border: var(--borde-identificador);
      }
      .social {
        grid-area: social; /*nombre del grid-area*/
        border: var(--borde-identificador);
      }
    </style>
    <div class="section">
      <div class="descripcion">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor aut similique autem quae, molestias consectetur assumenda dolorem atque vel alias aliquam saepe, nemo in quo sequi sunt. Ea, veniam odit.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor aut similique autem quae, molestias consectetur assumenda dolorem atque vel alias aliquam saepe, nemo in quo sequi sunt. Ea, veniam odit.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor aut similique autem quae, molestias consectetur assumenda dolorem atque vel alias aliquam saepe, nemo in quo sequi sunt. Ea, veniam odit.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor aut similique autem quae, molestias consectetur assumenda dolorem atque vel alias aliquam saepe, nemo in quo sequi sunt. Ea, veniam odit.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor aut similique autem quae, molestias consectetur assumenda dolorem atque vel alias aliquam saepe, nemo in quo sequi sunt. Ea, veniam odit.vLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor aut similique autem quae, molestias consectetur assumenda dolorem atque vel alias aliquam saepe, nemo in quo sequi sunt. Ea, veniam odit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor aut similique autem quae, molestias consectetur assumenda dolorem atque vel alias aliquam saepe, nemo in quo sequi sunt. Ea, veniam odit.v
        
      </div>
      <div class="vacio">
        
      </div>
      <div class="social">
        Aquí los enlaces a Facebook
      </div>
    </div>
```

- [Aquí puedes leer mas sobre el soporte de GRID](https://caniuse.com/#search=css-grid)
- [CSS Grid specificación](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#placement-shorthands)

Comment: Entiendo, aunque no exista la columna central en la grilla si existe. Gracias por la colaboración me ha ayudado mucho, si bien luego tuve que hacer una caja dentro y aplicarle un display:flex y una justificacion a la derecha tu colaboración fue de mucha ayuda

Comment: @MarceloPírez considera publicar entonces tu solución